# Установка обновлений для Windows

Tags: windows, update, установка

Есть загрузочная флешка с Windows Server 2008. После её установки необходимо скачать и установить множество обновлений с узла Microsoft. На всё про всё уходит в среднем 2 часа (в зависимости от машины). Теперь вопрос: как мне ускорить этот процесс? Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если необходимо устанавливать ОС на несколько машин, либо, в принципе, нужна частая установка, я бы задумался об интеграции обновлений в дистрибутив (заодно можно и необходимые драйверы интегрировать).

В зависимости от статуса лицензии/активации есть несколько способов. Для организации, наверное, лучшим вариантом будет [DISM](http://www.thevista.ru/forums.php?m=posts&q=15443&d=0). Выкачать обновления для интеграции проще всего, пожалуй, через [WSUS offline](http://www.wsusoffline.net/).

Чтобы не зацикливать вас только на этих вариантах, могу предложить также вариант с использованием [sysprep+WAIK](http://interface31.ru/tech_it/2014/10/sozdaem-svoy-distributiv-windows-7.html), а также ознакомиться с [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn475741.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

1. Обновление свежеустановленной ОС происходит всегда дольше, чем последующие регулярные обновления.
2. Как вариант для ускорения обновлений - развернуть собственный локальный сервер WSUS.